# How can I get data order by specified value list and remaining not found values from list at last in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have tried following code to order records using values but the issue generates for not found values from list of values

```
select * from `products` where `sku` != '' and `sku` != '0' order by FIELD(id, 193566,193562,223672,242812,202699,1191,321881,321507,201040,362393,562,328690,326,253653,202698,321501,58910,1190,305767,160435,1192,321505)
```

How can I do ordering like the list of above ids first and other values at last using order by Field() or any other way in MySql?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like...

```
select p.*, FIELD(id, 193566,193562,223672,242812,202699,1191,321881,321507,201040,362393,562,328690....) as ord
    from `products` p
    where `sku` != '' and `sku` != '0' 
    order by if(ord=0,10000000,ord)
```

(I've abbreviated the list so you will need to complete it ).  The if value of 10000000 is a dummy value, you could do something like `10000000+id` to give the remaining items some sort of order as well.